# AvroIO fails java.lang.ClassCastException to read logicaltype date

Tags: apache-spark, jodatime, avro, apache-beam

I am using AvroIO from Apache Beam with Spark Runner. I have defined a avro record with field

```
{
          "name" : "serviceDate",
          "type" : [ "null", {
            "type" : "int",
            "logicalType" : "date"
          } ],
          "doc" : "date",
          "default" : null
        }
```

Reading this data fails with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.joda.time.LocalDate

I am using avro 1.8.2

Comment: Anuj, can you provide more details, how your pipeline looks like? How do you use the AvroIO?

Comment: I found this to be an issue with Avro 1.8.2. Seems they missed implementing the logical types. Hive SerDe overcame this problem by explicitly handling logical types like date, decimal etc.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same Avro issue. Switching to Avro 1.9.0 solved the problem as Joda time is no longer used ([AVRO-2079](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2079)).